# Can't upload my app to Fabric, CrashLytics

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

Android Studio 3.6

Can't upload to Fabric
 In my Main.kt

```
private fun initFabric() {
      val crashlyticsKit = Crashlytics.Builder().core(CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build()).build()
      Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit, Crashlytics())
}
```

in build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') { transitive = true; }

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Run my app. Nice.

But my app can't upload to fabric. Here screenshot of Fabric plugin in Android Studio

[image]

and nothing happened.

Why?

Comment: fabric is moving to firebase, are you using it from firebase?

Comment: No, I'm not using it from firebase

Comment: have a look at fabric maybe at the end of this year they are moving to firebase

Comment: After I run my app on Emulator, then ii success distribute to Fabric. Nice.

Comment: I found the problem. Device has not internet. After connect, then this fix problem